# KVO on helper property

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing, reactive-cocoa

I have a property to an object instance in my class

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MyObject *myObject;
```

And I expose a helper property.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL hasMyObject
```

Which does

```
return self.myObject != nil;
```

I need hasMyObject to be KVO compliant (I am using RAC on it). To solve this I currently call:

```
- (void)app_setMyObject:(MyObject*)myObject
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@keypath(self.hasMyObject)];
    self.myObject = myObject;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@keypath(self.hasMyObject)];
}
```

every time I set myObject.

In this way an observer can know when `hasMyObject` changes.
My question is:
1. Is this OK
2. Is there a better way to do it?

---

Why do I do this at all?
Why not just use `myObject` property?

It is an API design thing. The `myObject` property is internal and should not be exposed publicly and `myObject` is only set from within the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a better way:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingHasMyObject {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@keypath(ClassName.new, myObject)];
}
```

Of course, `ClassName.new` is never actually evaluated (look at the expansion of `@keypath`), but it's the only way to get an instance keypath from a class method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that ClassName.new is never evaluated.